# How to resign/modify a standard Android app?

Tags: android, junit, adb

I am using Android's extensions for Eclipse and the JUnit framework to benchmark Android applications w.r.t. performance. As I want to compare my apps with built-in Android apps (e.g., Android's built-in browser), I need to resign these apps to be able to instrument them with the JUnit instrumentation runner.

I am able to fetch the apps from the system/app directory from my phone as well as to resign them using the re-sign.jar. However, I am not able to replace the app on my phone with the resigned version.

I tried both

```
adb install -r Resigned.app
```

and

```
abd uninstall com.android.<originalapp>
```

but both do not work.

Is the replacement of standard apps even possible?

Can I replace the apps by overwriting ther apk files under system/app?

Answer (score 0):

You can only replace or uninstall system apps on a rooted device.  It's not possible on an unrooted (normal) device.

If your device *is* rooted, something like this should work to replace a system APK:

```
adb shell su -c "mount -o rw,remount /system"
adb shell su -c "chmod 777 /system/app/"

adb push Re-signed.apk /system/app/original.apk

adb shell su -c "chmod 755 /system/app/"
adb shell su -c reboot
```

But be sure you know what you're doing if you do that! At the very least, be sure to keep the original around.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below commands to finish that:

```
adb shell mount -o remount rw /system/

adb push Resigned.apk /system/app
```